# Cassandra DB: is it favorable, or frowned upon, to index multiple criteria per row?

Tags: data-structures, cassandra

I've been doing a lot of reading lately on Cassandra, and specifically how to structure rows to take advantage of indexing/sorting, but there is one thing I am still unclear on; how many "index" items (or filters if you will) should you include in a column family (CF) row?

Specifically: I am building an app and will be using Cassandra to archive log data, which I will use for analytics.

Example types of analytic searches will include (by date range):

- total visits to specific site section
- total visits by Country
- traffic source

I plan to store the whole log object in JSON format, but to avoid having to go through each item to get basic data, or to create multiple CF just to get basic data, I am curious to know if it's a good idea to include these above "filters" as columns (compound column segment)?

Example:

```
   Row Key       | timeUUID:data | timeUUID:country | timeUUID:source |
                 ======================================================
timeUUID:section |  JSON Object  |       USA        |   example.com   |
```

So as you can see from the structure, the row key would be a compound key of timeUUID (say per day) plus the site section I want to get stats for. This lets me query a date range quite easily.

Next, my dilemma, the columns. Compound column name with timeUUID lets me sort & do a time based slice, but does the concept make sense?

Is this type of structure acceptable by the current "best practice", or would it be frowned upon? Would it be advisable to create a separate "index" CF for each metric I want to query on? (even when it's as simple as this?)

I would rather get this right the first time instead of having to restructure the data and refactor my application code later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea behind this is OK. It's a pretty common way of doing timeslicing (assuming I've understood your schema anyway - a create table snippet would be great). Some minor tweaks ...

You don't need a timeUUID as your row key. Given that you suggest partitioning by individual days (which are inherently unique) you don't need a UUID aspect. A timestamp is probably fine, or even simpler a varchar in the format YYYYMMDD (or whatever arrangement you prefer).

You will probably also want to swap your row key composition around to section:time. The reason for this is that if you need to specify an IN clause (i.e. to grab multiple days) you can only do it on the last part of the key. This means you can do WHERE section = 'foo' and time IN (....). I imagine that's a more common use case - but the decision is obviously yours.

If your common case is querying the most recent data don't forget to cluster your timeUUID columns in descending order. This keeps the hot columns at the head.

Double storing content is fine (i.e. once for the JSON payload, and denormalised again for data you need to query). Storage is cheap.

I don't think you need indexes, but it depends on the queries you intend to run. If your queries are simple then you may want to store counters by (date:parameter) instead of values and just increment them as data comes in.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, very helpful. I was also thinking about a simple date in the row key but your advice on the YYYYMMDD format is great. Also, the column compound key order; I'm obviously new to Cassandra and this advice is gold.